# скалярное произведение элементов матрицы в динамическом массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

по заданию необходимо определить пару строк с наибольшим скалярным произведением. Всё это в динамическом массиве. Матрица А(n*n). Эта программа вычисляет только подряд идущие строки, а надо, чтобы если были нули(как на картинке) эту строку просто не брало бы, а вычисляло те, где нулей нет. Надеюсь, правильно объяснила. Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<malloc.h>
using namespace std;

void clearMas(int** x, int n)/* очищение дин.массива*/
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] x[i];
    delete[] x;
}

void outMas(int** x, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> x[i][j];  // считываем числа в ячейки массива
        }

    }
    cout << "Исходная матрица: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << x[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void scalar(int max, int max1, int max2, int n, int **x) {
    int tmp = 0, sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int p1 = x[i][j];
            int p2 = x[i - 1][j];
            tmp = p1 * p2; /*вычисляем скалярное произведение*/
            sum += tmp;

        }
        if ((max < sum) and (sum != 0)) {
            max = sum;
            max1 = i;
            max2 = i + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Наибольшее скалярное произведение = " << max;
    cout << "\nСтрока: " << max1;
    cout << "\nСтрока: " << max2;

}

int main() {
    int  n=0,**x, max=0, tmp=0, sum=0, max1=0, max2=0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите числа: ";
    x = new int* [n];    // создаем динамический массив
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = new int[n];
    }
    outMas(x,n);
    scalar(max,max1,max2,n,x);
    clearMas(x,n);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: результат работы]

Comment: заменить ```tmp = p1 * p2;``` на ```tmp = (p1==0?1:p1) * (p2==0?1:p2);```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков , но при этом неправильно считает скалярное произведение

Comment: А почему оно должно быть верным если вы выкинули часть чисел?)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
void scalar(int n, int **x)
{
    int max1 = 0, max2 = 0, val = INT_MIN;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)  // Если произведение только РАЗНЫХ
        {                            // строк, заменить на int j = i + 1
            int s = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) s += x[i][k]*x[j][k];
            if (s > val)
            {
                val = s;
                max1 = i;
                max2 = j;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Наибольшее скалярное произведение = " << val;
    cout << "\nСтрока: " << max1;
    cout << "\nСтрока: " << max2;
}
```